# RestKit retain CoreData objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, restkit

I'm using RestKit in an application and I configured the mappers and works fine.I've decided used CoreData for caching,and the usual fecthController for display the core data models in a table view.The first screen of my app is a UITabViewController with three tabs. In each tab I have different information from different entities, I can switch between the tabs and all works fine. The problem is when I do a search in a tab, I lost the data from other tabs. I've dig deep in the problem and I've seen the following: when I search for something is deleting my other entities!!. I've tried to create different contexts and some stuff related with core data but nothing works.

```
// Configuration stuff
    let objectManager: RKObjectManager = RKObjectManager(baseURL: baseURL);
    let managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)!;
    let managedObjectStore: RKManagedObjectStore = RKManagedObjectStore(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel);
    objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;     
    managedObjectStore.createPersistentStoreCoordinator();
    do {
        try managedObjectStore.addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath(storePath, fromSeedDatabaseAtPath: seedPath, withConfiguration: nil, options: nil);
    } catch let err as NSError {
        fatalError()
    }

    // Create the managed object contexts
    managedObjectStore.createManagedObjectContexts();
    managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache =  RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache(managedObjectContext:      managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext)

// Mapping
    let entityMapping: RKEntityMapping = RKEntityMapping(
      forEntityForName: "Entity",
      inManagedObjectStore: RKObjectManager.sharedManager().managedObjectStore
    );
    entityMapping.identificationAttributes = ["id"];

    entityMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromArray([
      "id", "firstName", "lastName", "birthdate"
    ]);

    //Get Data from server
    class Datalist{
        class fun fetchData(successClosure:[Entity]->Void,failure:String->Void){
           RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath(
                    path,
                    parameters: nil,
                    success: {
                        ( operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, result: RKMappingResult!) -> Void in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            () -> Void in
                            successClosure(result.array());
                        });
                    },
                    failure: {
                        ( operation: RKObjectRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            () -> Void in
                            failureClosure();
                        });
                    }
                );
            }
     }
}
//Show data
class ListViewController:NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

       private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController!;

       override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad();
          fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
          fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore().mainQueueManagedObjectContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: "formatted",
            cacheName: nil)

          fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self
          getData()
       }

       private func getData(){
           DataList.fetchData({data in
              let ids = getEntitiesId(data)
              fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = createPredicateFromIds(ids)
              try! self.fetchedResultsController?.performFetch() 
           },failure:{message in 
               showMessage(message)
           })
       }

       func createPredicateFromIds( entityIds: [Int] ) -> NSPredicate {
        let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate( format: "id IN $ENTITYIDS" ).predicateWithSubstitutionVariables(["ENTITYIDS" : entityIds]);
        return predicate;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to show some code and give details of how you tested and what you actually see disappear

Comment: I provided an example! Thank you @Wain

Comment: So what is data list and what are the ids you're using with the predicate? Does the predicate just exclude everything?

Comment: Datalist retrieves data from the server using RestKit and finally refreshing the table getting the objects from core data.

Comment: So either the predicate is wrong or you simply need to refresh the UI when you set the new predicate

Comment: No tre predicate isn't wrong. The problem is the 3 tab controllers are sharing the same managedObjectContext

Comment: If you delete the object it doesn't cease to exist, each controller should have its own FRC

Comment: Yes, but the persisent storage it shared by the contexts and when you try to fetch all info gets a fault

Comment: Fault just means it isn't loaded from disk

Comment: Yes @Wain and the the properties and relationships comes nil

Comment: Only when logging, if you use it properly in code it'll get loaded

Comment: Can you show me code of what your object mapping looks like? It would also be helpful to see the predicate you are using.

Comment: Added the mappings and the predicate @Erik Johansson, but I think this isn't the problem because works fine. The problem is some times RestKit delete objects from the context

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've see the problem, it's regarding the deletion of orphaned objects. Because in the three tabs are different entities and when I perform a search in the entity makes the other entities as orphaned and delete the data! Only override this property:

```
override var deletesOrphanedObjects: Bool  {
        get{
            return false;
        }
        set{

        }
    };
```